# PHP mysqli prepared statement for stored procedure with out parameter

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have a stored procedure IsUserPresent like:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE IsUserPresent(
    in userid varchar (150),
    out isPresent bit
)
BEGIN
    SET isPresent=0;
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    INTO isPresent
    FROM users_table
    WHERE users_table.userid=userid;
END$$
```

and I want to call it from PHP using mysqli prepared statement. I am doing it following code snippet but it gives me warning.

```
$connect=&ConnectDB();
$stmt=$connect->prepare("CALL IsUserPresent(?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param('si',$uid,$userCount);
$stmt->execute();
$toRet = $userCount!=0;
Disconnect($connect);
return $toRet;
```

Warnings are as follow:

```
Premature end of data (mysqlnd_wireprotocol.c:1112)
Warning: mysqli_stmt::execute(): RSET_HEADER packet 1 bytes shorter than expected
Warning: mysqli_stmt::execute(): Error reading result set's header
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way stored procedures work with prepared statements is a bit more complicated. [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.stored-procedures.php) states that you've got to use session variables (MySQL sessions, not PHP)

> INOUT/OUT parameter
>
> The values of INOUT/OUT parameters are accessed using session variables.

So you could do it with

```
$connect=&ConnectDB();
// bind the first parameter to the session variable @uid
$stmt = $connect->prepare('SET @uid := ?');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $uid);
$stmt->execute();

// bind the second parameter to the session variable @userCount
$stmt = $connect->prepare('SET @userCount := ?');
$stmt->bind_param('i', $userCount);
$stmt->execute();

// execute the stored Procedure
$result = $connect->query('call IsUserPresent(@uid, @userCount)');

// getting the value of the OUT parameter
$r = $connect->query('SELECT @userCount as userCount');
$row = $r->fetch_assoc();               

$toRet = ($row['userCount'] != 0);
```

**Remark:**

I recommend to rewrite this procedure as a function with one IN parameter that returns INT.