# Combining PHP prepared statements with MySQL stored procedures

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I am working on a hobby comic website, and I am trying to use a stored procedure that inserts comic data into the database. There's a lot of info to dump in, so the parameter list is large, but it doesn't return any values.

```
PROCEDURE `update_comic`(IN cid int, title varchar(50), url varchar(100), sched int, 
nsfw char(1), form int, 
m tinyint, t tinyint, w tinyint, r tinyint, f tinyint, s tinyint, n tinyint)
```

I would like to call this stored procedure using a prepared statement. My first attempt looked like this:

```
if(!$stmt = $db->prepare("CALL update_comic(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"))
    {echo "Prepare UPDATE didn't work";}

if(!$stmt->bind_param("issisiiiiiiii",$cid, $ti, $url, $schedule, $nsfw, 
$form, $m, $t, $w, $r, $f, $s, $n))
    {echo "Bind UPDATE didn't work";}

if(!$stmt->execute())
    {echo "Execute UPDATE didn't work";}
```

But it returned "**Notice: Array to string conversion**" on the stmt->execute() line, and the execute update failed. I did some reading and gathered that this is because execute() takes an array of parameters if you don't use bind_param(), so ergo my bind_param wasn't working correctly.

I referred to this [PHP mysqli prepared statement for stored procedure with out parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25686733/php-mysqli-prepared-statement-for-stored-procedure-with-out-parameter) Stack Overflow thread and this http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.stored-procedures.php PHP documentation, among others. I tried using MySQL session variables with this prepare method

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('SET @cid := ?');
$stmt->bind_param('i', $cid);
$stmt->execute();
```

for each variable, the full list of which I will not submit my gracious readers to, and this

```
if(!$stmt = $db->prepare("CALL update_comic(@cid, @ti, @ur, @sch, @ns, 
@frm, @m, @t, @w, @r, @f, @s, @n)"))
    {echo "Prepare UPDATE didn't work";
    $result = false;} 

if(!$stmt->execute())
    {echo "Execute UPDATE didn't work";
    $result = false;}
```

execution strategy. This gave the same error as before. Does anyone have a way to call a prepared statement with this many variables, using stored procedures?

Thanks!

Comment: It's a very simple problem.  Atleast one of these is an array whereas it should not be. `$cid, $ti, $url, $schedule, $nsfw, 
$form, $m, $t, $w, $r, $f, $s, $n` . Check all to see which one is an array since your code is expecting a string