# why i cannot call the procedure from php?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm tring to call a procedure from PHP, but I can't do it.
Here is the Mysql code:

```
 CREATE DEFINER=`zygycoil`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `test`(OUT `a` INT, IN `b`INT, IN `c` INT)
NOT DETERMINISTIC MODIFIES SQL DATA SQL SECURITY DEFINER SET a=c+b
```

All the function has to do is return the result of 2 in variables (it's only an example of what I need to do).

Here's my php code

```
<?php

if ($mysqli->query("SET @x := 1;") &&  $mysqli->query("SET @y := 1;")  &&   $mysqli->query("SET @msg := 0;") ){
if (!$res = $mysqli->query("CALL test(@x,@y,@msg)", MYSQLI_USE_RESULT)) {
 //if (!$mysqli->query("CALL test(@x,@y)")) {
echo "CALL failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}
} else {
echo "CALL failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}
while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()){
 var_dump($row);
}
if ($res = $mysqli->query("SELECT @msg")) {
   while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()){
  print_r ($row);
}
}
?>
```

I looked around a lot on google but couldn't figure out what the problem was. Then I added the `$mysqli->errno` and i got this error:

```
 "CALL failed: (1414) OUT or INOUT argument 1 for routine zygycoil_data.test is not a variable or NEW pseudo-variable in BEFORE trigger"
```

Comment: You're calling it just fine, there is an error in the procedure.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25686733/php-mysqli-prepared-statement-for-stored-procedure-with-out-parameter

Comment: all the procedure is doing is "SET a=c+b"..look above on the creation. what can be wrong there?, also the procedure is runnig from the db itself

Comment: @JayBlanchard : sorry; fixed. also http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.stored-procedures.php

Comment: Can't this be done in a transaction?!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok thanks to alex thats the solution that works!

```
<?php   if ($mysqli->query("SET @x := 1;") &&  $mysqli->query("SET @y := 1;") &&   $mysqli->query("SET @msg := 0;") ){
if (!$res = $mysqli->query("CALL test(@x,@y,@msg)")) {
 //if (!$mysqli->query("CALL test(@x,@y)")) {
  echo "CALL failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}
} else {
echo "CALL failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}
if ($res = $mysqli->query("SELECT @msg")) {
while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()){
  print_r ($row['@msg']);
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, but try this way:

```
if ($mysqli->query("SET @x := 1;") &&  $mysqli->query("SET @y := 1;"  &&   $mysqli->query("SET @msg := 0;") {
   if (!$res = $mysqli->query("CALL test(@x,@y,@msg)", MYSQLI_USE_RESULT)) {
   //if (!$mysqli->query("CALL test(@x,@y)")) {
    echo "CALL failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
    }
} else {
    echo "CALL failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}
```

and to output for now try:

```
if ($res = $mysqli->query("SELECT @msg")) {
    while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()){
      print_r $row;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but it doesnt work it getting me this syntax error:"CALL failed: (1064) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET @y := 1 ; CALL test(@x,@y,@msg)' at line 1

Comment: what is error message? try to `if (!$mysqli->query("CALL test(@x,@y)")) {`

Comment: doesnt work: for the second try this is the error:"good1CALL failed: (1318) Incorrect number of arguments for PROCEDURE zygycoil_data.test; expected 3, got 2

Comment: so let's try to prepare the third parameter then :-) check update

Comment: my mistake, the first one looks good i think, can you also help with the fetch shuold it be " while($row = $res->fetch_object()){
  echo $row['msg'];}  res is the result of second if

Comment: i updated my question so you can see my code also i tried to use var_dump but still cant get nothing..

Comment: ooops...just fount another solution `if ($res = $mysqli->query("SELECT @msg")) {` check update

Comment: the output shuold be only a number..and it suppsoed to be 2 becuse it reurns a+b and you set a and b to be 1, look above on my procedure she only set the output to be a+b

Comment: ok fond one problem, it returns Array ( [@msg] => 2 ), but how can i get only the number

Comment: simply `$row['@msg']`