# mysqli handle prepared procedure call with multiple result sets with different columns

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

Is there a way to handle multiple result sets from a single prepared query when the result sets have different columns?

I have a procedure like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_CountAndList (in_SomeValue int)
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS ListCount FROM Table WHERE SomeValue = in_SomeValue;

  SELECT
    Name, Cost, Text
  FROM Table WHERE SomeValue = in_SomeValue
  ORDER BY
    Name
  LIMIT 25;
END
```

And my PHP code looks like this:

```
$some_value = $_POST["SomeValue"];

if($some_value != null) {
    $dbh = mysqli_connect(...connection stuff...) or die ('I cannot connect to the database.');

    $query = $dbh->prepare("CALL usp_CountAndList( ? );");
    $query->bind_param("i", $some_value);
    if($query->execute() == true) {
        $meta = $query->result_metadata();
        $fields = $meta->fetch_fields();
        var_dump($fields);

        $query->store_result();
        $query->bind_result($list_count);
        while($query->fetch()) {
            print_r("<TR>");
            print_r("<TD>" . $list_count ."</TD>");
            print_r("</TR>\n");
        }

        $query->free_result();
        $dbh->next_result();

        $meta = $query->result_metadata();
        $fields = $meta->fetch_fields();
        var_dump($fields);

        $query->store_result();
        $query->bind_result($name, $cost, $text);

        while($query->fetch()) {
            print_r("<TR>");
            print_r("<TD>" . $name . "</TD>");
            print_r("</TR>\n");
        }

        $query->free_result();
        $dbh->next_result();
    }
    else {
        print_r("Query failed: " . $query->error . "<BR>\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    $query->close();
    $dbh->close();
}
```

The issue I'm running into is that it looks like I'm getting the same meta-data for the second result set, even though it is returning a completely different set of columns, which means that my second bind_result call results in the following error:

```
PHP Warning:  mysqli_stmt::bind_result() [<a href='mysqli-stmt.bind-result'>mysqli-stmt.bind-result</a>]: Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement
```

I've banged my head against this for a while and am just not clear on what I'm doing wrong...it almost seems like a mysqli bug. Does anyone have some example code to show how to do what I'm attempting?

Comment: Hi I'm not quiet sure but solution for your problem might be here [click me](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25686733/php-mysqli-prepared-statement-for-stored-procedure-with-out-parameter) i think that your problem is in way you bind parameter in statement when call stored procedure...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically there are a few requirements to make this work properly...

- [MYSQL 5.5.3 or higher](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/c-api-prepared-call-statements.html)
- [PHP 5.3 for mysqlnd support](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysqlnd.php)

  - This is a compile time setting so if you are using shared hosting you probably cannot change this.

Basically in your example, use $query->next_result() instead of $dbh->next_result().

mysqli_stmt::next_result

I've only found one [SO example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31005065/1154453) of some else attempting to do this.