# dynamically bind_result bug workaround

Tags: php

I'm building a small framework to dynamically query a database and return all result sets on that query. For this method to work I have to deal with procedures that returns more than one result set, so I will put a while based on the next_result() condition being true. The following code works ok, but when I uncomment the second fetch() while, the var_dump next_result() always returns true. I think it is some kinda of bug or something. But because of this I cant manage this code to work.

Any tips? Any workaround?

```
    public function query($database, $method, $parameters) {

        $database -> connect();

        $sql = "CALL" . " " . $method . "(" . (count($parameters) === 0 ? "" : (str_repeat("?, ", count($parameters) - 2) . "?")) . ");";

        $stmt = $database -> connection -> prepare($sql);

        if (count($parameters) > 0) {
            call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), $parameters);
        }

        $stmt -> execute();
        $stmt -> store_result();

        //  i will have a while here

        $i = 0;

        $metadata = $stmt -> result_metadata();
        $fields = $metadata -> fetch_fields();

        $columns = array();
        foreach ($fields as $field) {
            $j[$field -> name] = "";
            $columns[$field -> name] = &$j[$field -> name];
        }

        call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_result'), $columns);

        $rows[$i] = array();

        while ($stmt -> fetch()) {
            $row = new stdClass();
            foreach ($columns as $key => $value) {
                $row -> $key = $value;
            }
            $rows[$i] = $row;
        }

        $i++;

        var_dump($stmt -> next_result());

        $metadata = $stmt -> result_metadata();
        $fields = $metadata -> fetch_fields();

        $columns = array();
        foreach ($fields as $field) {
            $j[$field -> name] = "";
            $columns[$field -> name] = &$j[$field -> name];
        }

        call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_result'), $columns);

        $rows[$i] = array();

        /*while ($stmt -> fetch()) {
            $row = new stdClass();
            foreach ($columns as $key => $value) {
                $row -> $key = $value;
            }
            $rows[$i] = $row;
        }*/

        var_dump($stmt -> next_result());

        $stmt -> free_result();
        $stmt -> close();

        $database -> disconnect();

        return $rows;           

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution based on the metadata variable being false:

```
    public function query($database, $method, $parameters) {

        $database -> connect();

        $sql = "CALL" . " " . $method . "(" . (count($parameters) === 0 ? "" : (str_repeat("?, ", count($parameters) - 2) . "?")) . ");";

        $stmt = $database -> connection -> prepare($sql);

        if (count($parameters) > 0) {
            call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), $parameters);
        }

        $stmt -> execute();
        $stmt -> store_result();

        $i = 0;

        while ($metadata = $stmt -> result_metadata()) {

            $fields = $metadata -> fetch_fields();

            $columns = array();
            foreach ($fields as $field) {
                $j[$field -> name] = "";
                $columns[$field -> name] = &$j[$field -> name];
            }

            call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_result'), $columns);

            $rows[$i] = array();

            while ($stmt -> fetch()) {
                $row = new stdClass();
                foreach ($columns as $key => $value) {
                    $row -> $key = $value;
                }
                $rows[$i] = $row;
            }

            $i++;
            $stmt -> next_result();

        }

        $stmt -> free_result();
        $stmt -> close();

        $database -> disconnect();

        return $rows;           

    }
```

Comment: To do this 2 things are required [MYSQL 5.5.3 or higher](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/c-api-prepared-call-statements.html) and 
[PHP 5.3 for mysqlnd support](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysqlnd.php) - This is a compile time setting so if you are using shared hosting you may not have this option available.